# Eclipse crashes every time I add a new xml file to my menu section - Android

Tags: android, eclipse, stack-overflow

My eclipse seems to crash every time with a Stackoverflow error every time I add an xml file to my Android project in the `/res/menu` section. Here's the error log that it generates, has anyone encountered this problem before?

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

Error
Thu Apr 28 10:34:18 EDT 2011
Unhandled event loop exception

java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.StructuredDocumentRegionProxy.setStructuredDocumentRegion(StructuredDocumentRegionProxy.java:338)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:423)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
.
.
.
repeats hundreds of times
```

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: It's just a new XML. I add it by right clicking `menu > new file > filename.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was doing was to do new file and change its extension to `.xml`. This is creating an empty xml in the menu section which was somehow triggering the stackoverflow exception. If I browse further down the list, there's an option to create a new `Android XML File` in Eclipse. It'll pre populate the XML with a `LinearLayout`, and the errors have stopped now.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution is the reason for the crash, maybe there is another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it is a problem similar to yours with ways to adjust memory allocation. Might help:
[StackOverflowError on Eclipse](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/76cbcd05653eb742/c9044b90e27be61d?lnk=gst&q=%22Unhandled%20event%20loop%20exception%22#c9044b90e27be61d)